# Looking to add a mouse down event listener to this code as well

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am making an etch a sketch website for The Odin Project.
While I have the base project finished, I want to add one more piece of functionality.
As of now, the mouse just needs to be hovering for the class to be added to black out to piece of the grid.
I want to make it so that you need to be hovering, and have the mouse left click held down.

Everything I have researched has been of no help to apply to my code without completely re-writing it, which I would not like to do.

Thank you in advance!

I assumed this would be as easy as adding "mousedown" into my event listener in my creatGrid function:
`.addEventListener('mouseover mousedown')`

This does not work, and made the listener stop working all together.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Etch-Your-Sketch</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/styles.css'>
    <script src='JS/scripts.js' defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Etch-Your-Sketch!</div>
    
        <button type="button" onclick="resetGame()">RESET</button>

        <div id="GRIDAREA"></div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #555;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 16px;
}

#GRIDAREA{
    display: flex;
    height: 512px;
    width: 512px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 2px solid #333fff;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

JS

```
createGrid(16);

function createGrid(size) {
    let gridWidthHeightValue = 512 / parseInt(size);
    gridWidthHeightValue = gridWidthHeightValue + "px";

    for(let i = 0; i < (size * size); i++){
        const container = document.getElementById("GRIDAREA");
        const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.style.width = gridWidthHeightValue;
        newDiv.style.height = gridWidthHeightValue;
        newDiv.classList.add('grid');
        container.appendChild(newDiv);
    }

    let gridBox = document.querySelectorAll(".grid");
    gridBox.forEach(box => {
        box.addEventListener('mouseover', () => box.classList.add("hover"));
    });

}

function resetGame() {
    const gridAreaDiv = document.getElementById("GRIDAREA");
    gridAreaDiv.innerHTML = '';    
    let gridSize = 0;
    while(gridSize < 16 || gridSize > 100) {
        gridSize = prompt("Enter a size for the grid, less than 100 and greater than 16:");
    }
    createGrid(gridSize);
}

function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: There is no event called `mouseover mousedown`. `addEventListener` won't allow for registering multiple events in one call. Remember it is not jQuery.